# Why would the joint density of X and Y be constant on the square $[-1,1]$ if they were independent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, independence, density-function

[image]

For question (ii) I don't understand the solution, which is:

[image]

What I don't understand:

Why would their joint density be constant on the square $[-1,1]$ if these variables were to be independent? And why is it not constant if their not independent? I don't understand anything to be honest in this solution to (ii), only the part which states that their densities are symmetric, which are equal to $\frac{1}{2}$ for $|x|\lt 1$. If someone could tell me where I could read up some theory for this or explain elaborately, it would be very helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been established in $(a)$ that $X,Y\sim U[-1,1]$. If $X,Y$ are independent, $f_{XY}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)=1/4$ for $-1\le x,y\le1$, which is not the case.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery It has been established that $X,Y\sim U[-1,1]$. Given their joint PDF, we need to determine whether they are independent.

Comment: @Aaron Edited to make it clearer.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri ohhh okay, I was confused by the word "constant", now I see...